# ffmpeg : Invalid file index 3 in filtergraph description

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to work out why I get the error message `Invalid file index 3 in filtergraph description` from the following command (ignoring the line breaks that I have put in for readability):

```
ffmpeg -y -progress .progressinfo.dat 
 -i "E:/tmp/f1.ts" 
 -i "E:/tmp/f2.ts" 
 -i "E:/tmp/f3.ts"  
 -filter_complex "
 [0][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=4.235:offset=3.235[vfade1];  
 [vfade1][2:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=6.562[vfade2];  
 [vfade2][3:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=10.183333333333,format=yuv420p;
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=1[afade1];  
 [afade1][2:a]acrossfade=d=1[afade2];  
 [afade2][3:a]acrossfade=d=1" 
 -movflags +faststart  "E:/tmp/_MERGED.mp4"
```

The full error is :

```
Invalid file index 3 in filtergraph description      [0] 
[1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=4.235:offset=3.235[vfade1];       [vfade1] 
[2:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=6.562[vfade2];       [vfade2] 
[3:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=10.183333333333,format=yuv420p;     [0:a] 
[1:a]acrossfade=d=1[afade1];       [afade1][2:a]acrossfade=d=1[afade2];       [afade2] 
[3:a]acrossfade=d=1.
```

I'm reading that the problem is referring to the 4th input.. but I do not see where I reference the 4th input.

What is wrong?

Comment: You refer to it here `[vfade2][3:v]` and here `[afade2][3:a]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gyan - that worked (I referred to it `[vfade2][3:v]` and here `[afade2][3:a]`)